# Calling CRUD operations in Windows Service

Tags: c#, windows-services

Hi I am trying to understand how windows services work but I can not wrap my mind on how would I expose the service to a client.This is what I did so far:

I created windows service project and installed the service using installUtil in command prompt.

This is the code in the WidnowsService:

```
partial class EmployeeService : ServiceBase
{
    public EmployeeService()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    protected override void OnStart(string[] args)
    {
        System.IO.File.Create(AppDomain.CurrentDomain.BaseDirectory + "OnStart.txt");
    }

    protected override void OnStop()
    {

        System.IO.File.Create(AppDomain.CurrentDomain.BaseDirectory + "OnStop.txt");
    }
}
```

I started the service from the Computer Management Services and stopped it and saw that the OnStart.txt and OnStop.txt works.

What I wanted to ask is how I would from a client application this windows service project.If for example I had a class that has CRUD operations how would I call it from lets say a Web.Api project?

Answer (score 0):

You could use a self hosted [WCF](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms731082%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) service or better self host something like [Nancy](http://nancyfx.org/) inside your service.

There is documentation for self hosting Nancy [here](https://github.com/NancyFx/Nancy/wiki/Self-Hosting-Nancy).The client could then call either the WCF service or make calls to the Nancy based API. There are plenty of options.

Extra tip, look into [Topshelf](http://topshelf-project.com/), makes writing Windows Service a lot more humane.

There is a good blog post [here](http://codebetter.com/brendantompkins/2013/01/15/fun-with-the-nancy-self-host/) about self hosting Nancy using a TopShelf service.